# Switch: Misbehaving Client

Tags: switch, ip-forwarding-table

Consider a switch with an empty forwarding table. Connected clients are

```
* A (Port 1)
* B (Port 2)
* C (Port 3)
```

`A` wants to send a package P to `C`. When the switch receives this package, the switch learns that packages to `A` should be send to Port 1.

The switch now sends this package to Port 2 and 3. If all clients are behaving correctly, only `C` will reply (and S will get a correct entry in his forwarding table).

Assuming `B` is misbehaving and will always reply. The switch would then create an entry in the forwarding table that would direct all further packages destined for `C`, to `B`.

Or is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When A send a *frame* to C, the switch learn the *mac address* of A and *flood* the frame to all ports except 1 (since it received the frame on this port).

Such, B and C both receive the frame. Since the frame contains C mac address as destination address, B knows it is not the intended recipient and drop the frame. C process the frame and reply. The switch learns C mac address and add it to its table.

The only practical way for B to misbehave is to spoof the mac adress of C.
In this case both B and C will use the same mac address.

This scenario leads to unpredictable results, and intermittent communication failure.

Both B & C will respond and the switch will likely update its table with the latest.
Usually the switch will keep only one association mac address < - > port in its table, so depending on the traffic some time the frame destined to the duplicate MAC will be sent on port 2 and some time to port 3, but it will not be sent on both ports at a time.

Some switches have (configurable) protection against mac spoofing, but this is very brand/model dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary (frame, flood, spoof). What you are essentially saying is that 'Yes, thats how it is. Upper layers should care about that.', right?

Comment: it will cause communication failures, but upper layer don't care about mac addresses (they are not even aware the Ethernet is used at layer 2). This is a problem that must be addressed at layer 2.

Comment: It is, in fact, 100% *predictable*: the last known location of a MAC is where traffic will go. In this case, if "B" answers, that's where the traffic will go until (and if) "C" answers. It makes a serious mess, but it is not unpredictable. BTW, most enterprise level switches will mark this a "mac flap", and might shutdown the ports because of it.

Comment: well if you can predict, for any OS when it will send a frame, considering the many services running, even without any user action...